# Django Validation with clean not working

Tags: python, django

my `views.py`

```
class AccountListView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'accounts'
    model = models.Account

class AccountCreateView(CreateView):
    fields = ('foo', 'bar')
    model = models.Account
```

my `forms.py`

```
class AccountForm(forms.ModelForm):
    foo = forms.ModelDecimalField()
    bar = forms.ModelDateField()

    def clean_foo(self):
        foo_passed = self.cleaned_data.get("foo")
        if foo_passed > 1000:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Sorry, Maximum is 1000.")
        return foo_passed
```

my `template.html`

```
{{form.as_p}}
```

on my code above, iam trying to validate the input, if value higher than 1000 will raise error. But its not working, what i miss.

Comment: Please show the view.

Comment: What are ModelDecimalField and ModelDateField?

Comment: @Alasdair updated with my view

Comment: @DanielRoseman that field same on my models called foo bar

Comment: It’s ok to create a simplified example instead of showing your actual code, it can often make the question easier to understand. But you should make sure that the example code works. Django doesn’t have `forms.ModelDecimalField` or `forms.ModelDateField`, so it makes the question confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell your view to use your form class:

```
class AccountCreateView(CreateView):
    fields = ('foo', 'bar')
    model = models.Account
    form_class = AccountForm
```